# Next.js and Material-UI leading to invalid hook call?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I'm trying to use material-ui with next.js / react.js.

When applying a layout file through _app.js I'm getting an error.

This is using the example react.js template material-ui provides (so confusing why it wouldn't work simply - i get the impression that material-ui has issues with next.js generally?).

I've tried a few different approaches, changing document and app, still won't seem to work.

Here's the Layout.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import Divider from '@material-ui/core/Divider';
import IconButton from '@material-ui/core/IconButton';
import Badge from '@material-ui/core/Badge';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Link from '@material-ui/core/Link';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import ChevronLeftIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ChevronLeft';
import NotificationsIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Notifications';
import { mainListItems, secondaryListItems } from '../Sidebar/Sidebar';
import Chart from '../Charts/Chart';
import Deposits from '../Deposits';
import Orders from '../Orders';
import Menu from '../AppBar/Menu';

const drawerWidth = 240;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  ........

export default function Layout() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(true);
  const handleDrawerOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  };
  const handleDrawerClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };
  const fixedHeightPaper = clsx(classes.paper, classes.fixedHeight);

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Menu />
      <Drawer
        variant="permanent"
        classes={{
          paper: clsx(classes.drawerPaper, !open && classes.drawerPaperClose),
        }}
        open={open}
      >
        <div className={classes.toolbarIcon}>
          <IconButton onClick={handleDrawerClose}>
            <ChevronLeftIcon />
          </IconButton>
        </div>
        <Divider />
        <List>{mainListItems}</List>
        <Divider />

      </Drawer>
      {props.children}

    </div>
  );
}
//<List>{secondaryListItems}</List> later
```

Heres app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import App, { Container } from 'next/app';
import Head from 'next/head';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@material-ui/styles';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import theme from '../src/theme';

import Layout from '../components/Layout/Layout';

class MyApp extends App {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Remove the server-side injected CSS.
    const jssStyles = document.querySelector('#jss-server-side');
    if (jssStyles) {
      jssStyles.parentNode.removeChild(jssStyles);
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Head>
          <title>My page</title>
        </Head>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          <Layout>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
          </ Layout>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

export default MyApp;

and document.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Document, { Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import { ServerStyleSheets } from '@material-ui/styles';
import theme from '../src/theme';

class MyDocument extends Document {
  render() {
    return (
      <html lang="en">
        <Head>
          <meta charSet="utf-8" />
          {/* Use minimum-scale=1 to enable GPU rasterization */}
          <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="minimum-scale=1, initial-scale=1, width=device-width, shrink-to-fit=no"
          />
          {/* PWA primary color */}
          <meta name="theme-color" content={theme.palette.primary.main} />
          <link
            rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
          />
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </html>
    );
  }
}

MyDocument.getInitialProps = async ctx => {
  // Resolution order
  //
  // On the server:
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. document.getInitialProps
  // 4. app.render
  // 5. page.render
  // 6. document.render
  //
  // On the server with error:
  // 1. document.getInitialProps
  // 2. app.render
  // 3. page.render
  // 4. document.render
  //
  // On the client
  // 1. app.getInitialProps
  // 2. page.getInitialProps
  // 3. app.render
  // 4. page.render

  // Render app and page and get the context of the page with collected side effects.
  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;

  ctx.renderPage = () =>
    originalRenderPage({
      enhanceApp: App => props => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
    });

  const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);

  return {
    ...initialProps,
    // Styles fragment is rendered after the app and page rendering finish.
    styles: [
      <React.Fragment key="styles">
        {initialProps.styles}
        {sheets.getStyleElement()}
      </React.Fragment>,
    ],
  };
};

export default MyDocument;
```

And here is the error information.

```
×
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://xxxx-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
▶ 11 stack frames were collapsed.
ctx.renderPage
./pages/_document.js:60
  57 |  const sheets = new ServerStyleSheets();
  58 |  const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
  59 | 
> 60 |  ctx.renderPage = () =>
     | ^  61 |    originalRenderPage({
  62 |      enhanceApp: App => props => sheets.collect(<App {...props} />),
  63 |    });
View compiled
▶ 4 stack frames were collapsed.
This screen is visible only in development. It will not appear if the app crashes in production.
Open your browser’s developer console to further inspect this error.
```

Comment: Says it is not a function

Comment: Did you solve this ? I have the same problem

Comment: @MichaelHolborn did you manage to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware you cannot use hooks inside class components and your MyDocument is declared as a class. Maybe try converting it to a functional component.

Comment: The _document.js is from the materialui example for next.js . I think it should be okay as a class. But I will check at home

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem installing npm i @emotion/react @emotion/styled